# How do I find the time constant of this first order time delayed system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

I have the following first order system

$$ G(s) = \frac{3}{1 + Ts}e^{-sL} $$

to which as an experiment I give as an input the signal represented by the green graph below (a step input).
During the experiment a mistake occurred and the step response eventually rests at a saturated value of $A=85$ according to the below red graph.

[image: image of graphs]

I want to now figure out what the values of the parameters $T$ and $L$ are. The value for $L$ is simple enough as it's simply the time delay which I get to be $L=20$ using the graphs. It is with the time constant $T$ that I am getting stuck on. I honestly have no good idea of how to go about this, but here is what I've tried.

---

We have the system's transfer function $G(s)$ and we know that we have as an input a step response width a height of $70 - 30 = 40$ whose Laplace transform becomes $R(s) = 40/s$. The output becomes

$$ Y(s) = G(s)R(s) = \frac{3e^{-20s}}{1+Ts} \cdot \frac{40}{s} $$

I was thinking that this expression in the Laplace domain isn't to much use, so I made an attempt to find the inverse Laplace transform. To do this I begin by ignoring the exponential $e^{-20s}$ which is contributing to time delay and focus only on performing partial fraction decomposition on the remaining expression $ \frac{120}{s(1+Ts)} $.

$$ \frac{120}{s(1+Ts)} = \frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{1+Ts} $$

which after solving for $A$ and $B$ yields

$$ \frac{120}{s(1+Ts)} = \frac{120}{s} - \frac{120T}{1+Ts}. $$

Now bringing back the exponential term gives

$$ G(s) = \frac{120}{s}e^{-20s} - \frac{120T}{1+Ts}e^{-20s}. $$

Using the time shift property of the Laplace transform $f(t - t_{0})u(t - t_{0}) \iff F(s)e^{-st_{0}},\ t_{0} \geq 0$ I believe the inverse Laplace transform of the left term is

$$ 120u(t-20) $$

where $u(t)$ is the step (Heaviside) function. Regarding the right term I first rewrite it by multiplying the numerator and denomiator by $\frac{1/T}{1/T}$

$$ \frac{120T}{1+Ts}e^{-20s} = \frac{120}{s + \frac{1}{T}}e^{-20s} $$

so I can now use a table to find the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s + \frac{1}{T}}e^{-20s}$. I find that the inverse Laplace transform of $1/(s - \lambda)$ is $e^{\lambda t}u(t)$ and that in combination with the time shift property leads me to believe that the final inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{120T}{1+Ts}e^{-20s}$ is

$$ 120e^{-\frac{1}{T}(t-20)}. $$

Finally we have that the inverse Laplace transform of $G(s)$ is

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}(G(s)) = 120u(t - 20) - 120e^{-\frac{1}{T}(t-20)}. $$

I don't know if this is correct and even if it is, I am not sure if it's to any use. I have a gut feeling that I am going in the right direction and that I should be able to continue from here somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The shown step response and the transfer function don't fit together. According to the plot for the input, the input is at $\hat{u}=30$ before the step, and the output is clearly at steady state before the step. We can now use the final value theorem to determine the value the output should have before the step:
$$y(t=50)=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}G(s)\hat{u}=3\cdot 30=90$$
However, in the plot we have that $y(50)=20$. We can thus conclude that the shown step response for sure is from a different system. We thus stop here, since any further calculations would be meaningless.

Comment: PS: please check if the transfer function should have been $$ G(s) = \frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1 + Ts}e^{-sL} $$

Comment: In your reasoning you're assuming the input signal had a step from $0$ to $30$, right? I don't think that has to be the case, it could've been a smaller step. Furthermore, are you not missing an 's' when applying the final value theorem? In regards to checking the transfer function, To my knowledge the given transfer function is the correct one.

Comment: You are right, we don't know exactly how the input looked like for $t<50$. This does however not imply that we know nothing about the input before $t=50$. First, note that your system is (assymptotically and even exponentially) stable, since it has a pole at $s=-\frac{1}{T}$. This means that it "forgets" inputs "far in the past" (as a rule of thumb, inputs more than $5T+L$ in the past). Now, we see that around $t=50$, the output does not show any dynamics. Roughly,  this implies that the input must have been at $u=30$ for "a sufficiently long time" before $t=50$ such that...

Comment: ... we can as well assume that the input was at $u=30$ for all $t<50$, whose Laplace transform is $U=\frac{30}{s}$. We now get that $$y(50)=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}s Y(s)=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}s G(s) U(s)=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}s G(s)\frac{30}{s}=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}G(s)30=90$$. This poses the question: "How" do you know that the transfer function is correct? If it was given to you e.g. by a teacher, I would guess your teacher made a typo...

Comment: I see what you're getting at with your reasoning but am still not completely convinced. Where do you get $5T + L$ from and how does it tie into the current situation? Does that correspond to some kind of "we only remember input since $5T + L$ seconds back" reasoning which in this situation leads to us KNOWING that the signal MUST have been $u=30$ since $5T + L$ seconds back until $t=60$? If so, how do we know that? Also, why does the non-showing of dynamics at $t=50$ "roughly imply" that the input must've been at $u=30$ for all $t < 50$? ...

Comment: ... To me it seems like it remains that we do not know for sure what the input looked like for $t < 50$. We can at best give an educated guess on what it might look like, just like you did, but we still don't know for sure. Assuming that the given transfer function and the graphs are correct, can we come to some answer? Perhaps starting the way I did?

Comment: Let's try it from a maybe easier angle: A realization of your transfer function is $$\frac{d}{dt}y(t)=-\frac{1}{T}y(t)+\frac{3}{T}u(t-L).$$ You can validate this by calculating the TF of this ODE. We know that at $t=50$, we have $\frac{d}{dt}y=0$, thus $u(t-L)=const$ and $y(t)=3u(t-L)$. We have $y(t)=20$ which thus implies $u(t-L)=\frac{20}{3}$. However, in the plot we see $u=30$, which is a contradiction. Thus, either $u=\frac{20}{3}$ or the TF has to be multiplied by $\frac{2}{9}$, i.e. we need a $\frac{2}{3}$ instead of a $3$ in the numerator.